# Spring JUnit Mocking StrutsServlet finds wrong AppConfig

Tags: java, spring, junit, autowired

I have a JUnit-Class like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = AppConfig.class)
public class PricelistTest {

    @Autowired
    MyFormBean f;
    @Autowired
    MyActionBean a;

    @Test
    public void testAction(){
        MockServletContext c = new MockServletContext("/test");
        c.addInitParameter("contextClass", AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class.getCanonicalName());
        c.addInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", AppConfig.class.getCanonicalName());
        ServletContextListener listener = new ContextLoaderListener();
        ServletContextEvent event = new ServletContextEvent(c);
        listener.contextInitialized(event);
        MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        a.execute(null, f, request, response);
    }
```

This is my AppConfig

```
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    MyFormBean myFormBean(){
      return new MyFormBean();
    }
    @Bean
    MyActionBean myMyActionBean(){
      return new MyActionBean ();
    }
    @Bean
    MyService myService(){
      return new MyService();
    }
}
```

This is my MyActionBean

```
public class MyActionBean {
     @Autowired
     MyService service;
     ...
     public ActionForward execute(...) throws Exception {
         ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext()
            .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
            .autowireBean(this); <-- throws exception that no MyService bean found.
     }
}
```

The Situation:

- I have two Spring-Contexts: one for the JUnit, one for the MockedServlet.

The Problem:

- The MockedServlet can not autowire `MyService` because it never loads the `AppConfig`.

The Question:

- Can i put the JUnit-ApplicationContext into the MockedServlet?
- How can i force the MockedServlet to load the `AppConfig` configured by the `init-parameter` in the Test-Method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@BootstrapWith(WebTestContextBootstrapper.class)
```

to your Test-**Class**.

And add a autowired field of type `WebApplicationContext` that you use as an constructor-argument of the ContextLoaderListener like this:

```
@Autowired
WebApplicationContext ctx;

...
   ServletContextListener listener = new ContextLoaderListener(ctx);
...
```

Now you can drop the init-parameters.